# How to re-add string array into array adapter?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have the following list declaration:

```
final ArrayList<String> timeSlot = new ArrayList<String>();
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewtime);
```

I know that if I were to add a string array into a new adapter it would be just creating it like this :

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTime = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(
  this,
  R.layout.textv,
  timeSlot
);

list.setAdapter(adapterTime);
```

However, I want to re-add the adapter items after I have cleared it like this :

```
adapterTime.clear();
adapterTime.addAll(timeSlot);
list.setAdapter(adapterTime);
```

It doesn't seem to work. Anyone could give me some suggestions ?

EDIT:

this is the thing I wanna do :

```
if(radioA.isChecked()){                  
    if(adapterTime.getItem(adapterTime.getCount()-1).equals("20:00:00"))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        adapterTime.clear();
        adapterTime.addAll(timeSlot);
        adapterTime.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I added notifychanged but it still goes blank. The idea is that when I click on one hour which is radioA, it will check if it is equals to 20:00:00, if not then it will clear up and re-add everything.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could give a bit more context on what you're doing (e.g. the Android methods in which you're making these calls), so we can determine if perhaps it's just getting added at a point that isn't intuitive (and thus perhaps not being displayed)

Comment: `adapterTime.notifyDataSetChanged()` is missing there.

Comment: u dont need to setAdapter eveytime. Shark's answer must work. call notifyDataSetChanged every time when u change items

Comment: @uguboz it didnt work tho. i added both in the else and the first time where I set adapter.

Comment: calling `clear` followed by `addAll` just works

Comment: yeah it seems addAll already calls notifyDatasetChanged itself

Comment: @uguboz Yup, it does. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: make sure timeSlot is not empty and else condition is satisfied. u can put log output to see what is going on

Comment: @uguboz it works for the first time i set adapter. But if I were to re-add the elements, it seems like timeslot turns empty which I have no reason why. I tried to test it. It seems like if I don't clear it up, it will add all but up until 19:00:00 which is not supposed to be. It should add the remaining 19:30:00 and 20:00.

Comment: Then it is not related to arrayadapter but arraylist.

Comment: yup, it is new to me that arraylist item gone when u clear the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to this question is that when I cleared the adapter, the string array's items is cleared as well.
So I created another string array to save the variable to act as a temporary one. Pass it back to the original after it has been cleared.

```
 else{
                    adapterTime.clear();
                    if(timeSlot.isEmpty()){
                        for(int i = 0; i <timeSlot2.size();i++){
                            timeSlot.add(timeSlot2.get(i).toString());
                       }
                   }
                    adapterTime.addAll(timeSlot);
```

EDIT: This will create duplicate result as it the adapter is set as Final. I have no idea how to avoid this, since my codes are quite stuck in their own place.